# How do I avoid getting wedged between an outer water layer and the edge of the map?

Tags: brawl-stars

In Map Maker, I like to involve vast areas of water surrounding my solo/duo showdown map but when I play Darryl and role out into the open areas of water I seem to get wedged between the water and the edge of the map. Is there a way to avoid this? I can not place a wall on the outside because it involves a one block gap. How could I fix this water problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to Reddit, Darryl seems to glitch in the water areas because of his super attack.

The best thing to do is to not even place the items at all. This is a common issue for every player.

Comment: Your Reddit link just pointed to `reddit.com` aka the Reddit homepage. I've removed it for now as it made no sense, but can you provide the link to the actual comment/thread where this bug was discussed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how *much* water you have surrounding your maps. In most cases Darrel/Bull etc. will automatically "teleport" to the closest land *even through walls* (allowing for some clever plays on maps like "Island Invasion" and "Dark Passage").

However after a certain range (seems to be around 20+ tiles from any landmass - but don't quote me on that), a brawler can get **stuck**.
If you want to know if there is anyway to become unstuck, the answer is "not until you get another super".

If you want to know how to modify your map to prevent this issue (which you seem willing to try, using walls and such), there are definitely a few solutions.

Some things you could do:

1. Place walls that surrounds skulls, bounce pads, teleporters, or spawn points to avoid the one-block-gap issue. Also, remember walls will break into open spaces when a brawler such as Bull lands on them. Which could get them stuck out in the smoke and you are back at square one.
2. Simply place open spaces for a brawler to stop at much the same way you would place walls (but remember they should be able to get off of this somehow).
3. Use lots of water but don't "drown" your map. Large lakes or puddles work well in a map.

Unfortunately I none of the solutions will allow an "infinitely ranged Darrel super". But they should be adequate to design very watery maps without players getting frustrated by this glitch.